# Invalid dynamic table of SDL_Surface

Tags: c++, sdl

I'm having difficulties with creating dynamic table of SDL_Surface.
Take a look at that code:

```
SDL_Surface **testA = new SDL_Surface *[2];
for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
    testA[i] = new SDL_Surface;
SDL_Surface* testB[2];
```

As far as i'm concerned, TestA and textB should look identically. But Visual Studio locals look like that:
[image]

How should I fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try  this:

```
    int size=2;
    SDL_Surface** testA ; 
    testA  = new SDL_Surface*[size];  

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) 
    { 
      surface[i] = NULL; //  here, surface[i] is the kth pointer, not an SDL_Surface 
   // surface[i] = SDL_CreateRGBSurface ( /* set your parameters */ );
    } 


    // Of course, somewhere later in the code, you'll need to free the memory ... 
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) 
    { 
    SDL_FreeSurface(testA [i]); 
    testA [i] = NULL; 
    } 

    delete testA ;
```

Answer (score 1):

`SDL_Surface` shouldn't be allocated using `new`, but using the functions from the SDL API (e.g. `SDL_CreateRGBSurface`, `SDL_ConvertSurface`...) which will allocate it and initialize it properly.

If the problem is about the way Visual Studio debugger displays dynamically allocated arrays, you should look at that question: [How to display a dynamically allocated array in the Visual Studio debugger?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75180/how-to-display-a-dynamically-allocated-array-in-the-visual-studio-debugger)

Comment: Ok, I've fixed it. Later I'll post a solution.
Thanks!