# Adding derived objects into an array of (abstract) base pointers

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I ran into a problem when adding derived objects into an array of (abstract) base pointers. To simplify what I'm trying to do, here is an example:

```
Base** baseArray = new Base*[3];
baseArray[0] = new derived1(param,param);
baseArray[1] = new derived2(param,param);
baseArray[2] = new derived3(param,param);
```

Now, I have yet to get my virtual Print() working to print out the baseArray elements but using the vs2012 debugger I can only see baseArray[0] in baseArray. The other two are just gone.

But I guess my main question is that, should the example above work. If yes, would it be too much to ask of what could have happened. If not, is there a (better) way?

**Edit: Thank you all!**

Comment: What do you mean - is `baseArray[1]` an invalid pointer?

Comment: Reasonable question. Have +1'd and closed as dupe only to tidy-up.

Answer (score 3):

Your code is correct. Given a dynamically allocated array, Visual Studio debugger will only display the first element. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75180/how-to-display-a-dynamically-allocated-array-in-the-visual-studio-debugger) answer might help.

Comment: Thanks, I think you are right. I should asked sooner. :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it works just fine. The debugger is lying to you - probably because the static type of `baseArray` is pointer to pointer, not pointer to array of 3 elements.