# How to add debug watch for dynamically allocated array in CodeLite?

Tags: c++, arrays, codelite

I would like to check the content of elements in array, while debugging my program. But when I add watch for dynamically allocated array all I can see is address for pointer?

[image]

Is there a way to watch the content of dynamically allocated array? I went through the below post, but solution didn't seem to work for CodeLite. I guess its because of different debugger.

[How to display a dynamically allocated array in the Visual Studio debugger?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75180/how-to-display-a-dynamically-allocated-array-in-the-visual-studio-debugger)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had some success using a casting style syntax for the watch value:

```
(int[10]*)a
```

This shows all array values once expanded in the watch window. The declaration of `a` in the code was:

```
int *a = new int[10];
```

Here is the watch window:

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Daniel. That really helped.