# CPP , creating array and i see only one parameter

Tags: c++

i create an Array with 3 numbers;
i see only one number instead 3

```
int *ArrayA;
ArrayA = new int[3];
ArrayA[0] = 2;
ArrayA[1] = 4;
ArrayA[2] = 6;
```

when i debugging and follows ArrayA i see only 2;
what could be the problem?

Comment: Please make a [mre]. e.g. how are you printing the values?

Comment: If you're looking at it in a debugger, the debugger is completely unaware that `ArrayA` points to the first element of an array.

Comment: What debugger are you using? Here's the [dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75180/how-to-display-a-dynamically-allocated-array-in-the-visual-studio-debugger) if you're using VS

Comment: If you're using the Visual Studio debugger you can specify how many elements you want to display in the watch window: `ArrayA, 3` will show 3 elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a problem. It's as expected because `ArrayA` is a pointer. So pointer base address and the address of the 1st element of the array are same. Hence you always see `2` in your debugger. Not sure which debugger you are using, you can try to add `ArrayA[index]` or `*(ArrayA + index)` then you can see other values as well.

Answer (score 2):

Your object `ArrayA` is of type `int *`. Hence it points to a single `int`. The fact that you have it point at an `int[3]` array doesn't change that fact. Your debugger can also not guess that you want it to display more than one value.

---

Instead of using raw c-style arrays, it is usually recommended to use an [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array).

```
std::array<int,3> arrayA = {2,4,6};
```

Comment: And if you won't always have a size of `3`, consider using [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector). because you can change the size to whatever you need (within reason, of course).