# C++ Dynamic array not allocating memory

Tags: c++, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am working with dynamic arrays in C++ and trying to assign a memory allocation. But, as I debug, I found out that the memory is not being allocated.

In header file:

```
Data *_elements;
```

In cpp file constructor:

```
_elements = new Data[10];
```

where ***Data*** is a struct, consisting a **string** type and **int** type.

While I am debugging, I noticed that the elements are not being assigned with 10 memory allocations.
[image]

I would like to know what is that I am doing wrong. Thank you!

Comment: What evidence do you have that "the elements are not being assigned with 10 memory allocations"?  Why do you think there *should* be 10 allocations, as opposed to one big one?

Comment: Your debugger does not show all elements of the array. You can watch content with indices like `_elements[1]`

Comment: Thank you @İsmailDurmaz. Apparently, my debugger is not showing it!

Comment: @SasiKiranGaddipati -- You should have always suspected that it is the tool you're using to view the variables, and not the program itself.  It would be a big joke if a C++ compiler didn't produce the correct code to do a simple `new[]`.

Comment: fyi, `_elements` is a pointer, not an array, you just make it point to an array.

Comment: If you use Visual Studio you probably want to read about this method to get the debugger to show you the values of a dynamically allocated array: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75180/how-to-display-a-dynamically-allocated-array-in-the-visual-studio-debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75180/how-to-display-a-dynamically-allocated-array-in-the-visual-studio-debugger)

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that the memory is being allocated, it's just not showing up. If you perform anything using these memory locations you will have them show up in your debugger. For example:

```
//you have something like this in some statement
element[i] //where i is some variable between and including 1-9. lets say 3
```

You will have `element[3]` show up in the debugger.

P.S. I'm starting out with C++, and programming as a whole, so please do correct me if I am wrong.