# Constructor doesn't allocate

Tags: c++, constructor, clion

I have this class. Whenever I call the constructor, it gets called, for instance, with `segments = 4`. I get in `Segments` the address just for the first element instead of 4.

This is from clion debugger:

[image]

```cpp
class Image{

    LinkedList<int,int> UnLabeledSegments;
    int* Segments;
    int NumOfSegments;

public:

    explicit Image(int segments);
    ~Image();

};

Image::Image(int segments):Segments(new int[segments]),NumOfSegments(segments){


    for(int i = 0; i < segments;i++){
        this->UnLabeledSegments.insert(i,-1);
        this->Segments[i] = -1;
    }
    
}
```

This is how I call the constructor the container is simple BST dictionary

```
void ImageTagger::AddImage(int ImageID) {
    ImageContainer.insert(ImageID,(new Image(ImageSegments)));
}
```

Comment: You _do_ get 4 elements, your debugger just doesn't know the length so it can't show it correctly.

Comment: See also [array to pointer decay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-to-pointer-decay).

Comment: Avoid the keyword `new` in modern C++! `Image` should contain a `std::vector<int> Segments;` (which knows its own size), and probably `ImageContainer` should contain `Image` objects instead of `Image*` pointers.

Comment: I don't know if in Clion if there is an option to tell the debugger to display the rest. In Visual Studio  you can do this in the debugger by telling the debugger the number of elements to show. Related to this feature in Visual Studio: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75180/how-to-display-a-dynamically-allocated-array-in-the-visual-studio-debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75180/how-to-display-a-dynamically-allocated-array-in-the-visual-studio-debugger)

Comment: With your raw pointer usage (instead of `std::vector`), [the rule of 3/5/0](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) is probably going to bite you soon.  Your `Image` type is copyable, but you won't like what those copies do.

Comment: *Constructor doesn't allocate* -- The title is not really correct.  The constructor is working correctly.  It is your debugger that is not behaving.